# How to autoplay the vimeo video from flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, vimeo

I try to autoplay the vimeo video in flutter using flutter_inappwebview package
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

I readed many of the blogs. And my senior says to me to use the below function. Can anyone please tell me the exact code in flutter.
`mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);`

or if you have any other ideas to autoplay vimeo video in flutter please tell me the solutions for this issue